# Do correlations relate to PCA eigenvectors and can PCA be used for clustering?

Tags: pca

Does the magnitudes of principal eigenvectors obtained by PCA have anything to do with correlations of original variables, and can we use PCA for clustering?
Thanks!

Comment: These are two separate questions. The answer to the second is [yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Relation_between_PCA_and_K-means_clustering). The first one is too vague. First what is the magnitude of the vector? Also what kind of relationship you are looking for? Principal eigenvectors in PCA are the eigenvectors of either covariance or correlation matrix of original variables, so they are clearly related to correlations.

Comment: The wikipedia page is pretty verbose and should be sufficient for question #1, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis .

Comment: I think I provide an answer to question 2 in an earlier thread, [Classification after factor analysis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/classification-after-factor-analysis/3475#3475).

Answer (score 1):

@ q2: Ifyou use all principal components, then this is only a rotation in the multidimensional space and the euclidean(!) distances between datapoints are not affected.

However, for instance taxicab-distances are affected by rotation. (This ca be seen if you consider the unit square and the taxicab-distance between the two edges of the diagonal. Unrotated you have two times one border s the distance is 2, but if you rotate it by 45 deg you have the distance sqrt(2))

Furthermore, once you employ PCA then your goal is to reduce dimensionality, thus usually you discard variance/covariance (according to the ignored less-principal components), and this cannot be reflected by any selection of sets of items in a "canned" cluster-analysis, so the solutions must be different.
*[opinion] Well, that the PCA and the unrotated clusters are usually not perfectly equal need not mean, that the PCA-based clusters are worse/bad/meaningless [/opinion]*